# Dot NET MAUI and Dropbox API: Authorization Error

Tags: dropbox, maui

I follow this article's steps to integrate Dropbox into the .NET MAUI application.

https://medium.com/p/e51d9ae0b350#8ae1

The above article steps work fine in the Xamarin platform and the Dropbox login interface (refer to the screenshot attached) for Dropbox gets appropriately displayed. But, in the .NET MAUI application, I am facing an authorization error and the Dropbox login interface isn't displayed.

As mentioned in the article, I am using Webview to display the Dropbox login interface on a modal page. Please find the code snippet below.

```
 public async Task Authorize()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.AccessToken) == false)
            {
                // Already authorized
                this.OnAuthenticated?.Invoke();
                return;
            }

            if (this.GetAccessTokenFromSettings())
            {
                // Found token and set AccessToken 
                return;
            }

            // Run Dropbox authentication
            this.oauth2State = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            var authorizeUri = DropboxOAuth2Helper.GetAuthorizeUri(OAuthResponseType.Token, "yourDrobboxAppKey", new Uri("YourDropboxRedirectUri"), this.oauth2State);
            var webView = new WebView { Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = authorizeUri.AbsoluteUri } };
            webView.Navigating += this.WebViewOnNavigating;
            var contentPage = new ContentPage { Content = webView };
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(contentPage);
        }
```

**Screenshot (Xamarin):**

[image]

**Error (.NET MAUI):**

[image]

***Note:** I even continued the execution since the application is in break mode but then the application stops.*

Can someone let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: I can't offer help with .NET MAUI itself, but note that per [the Dropbox OAuth documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize), you should not present the Dropbox OAuth app authorization page in a web view.

Comment: Google more recently has repeated that such authorizations wll be blocked: [embedded webviews](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html): *"All embedded webviews will be blocked starting on September 30, 2021"*. That note explains why. Therefore, it is surprising that the Xamarin one still works. (legacy version of library perhaps, and maybe google decided not to break old apps.) Bottom line: Apps are required to direct the user to the device's built-in browser.